# TCA field of type group doesn't show records if there are too many items

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

In my own extension I have extended `fe_user` table to add some relations for users to sysfolders (pages with doktype 254). I did it with common TCA override and adding the `group` type. In general that works for **normal** amount of records (like several tens or so) but in some cases some users can have chosen up to 3000+ relations.

Unfortunately, in such case TYPO3 BE doesn't render these relations in form properly (it's empty, although database contains a list of 3000 comma-separated UIDs and FE plugins displays these relations properly).

Of course in such case after saving the form in BE causes that the DB column is cleared.

As you can see, I tried to increase the `maxitems` without result. Is there some other config option that I missed, or for such huge amount I should use another type of form field? Any advice will be highly appreciated.

File `typo3conf/ext/myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php`

```php
'tx_myext_points' => [
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label'   => 'Sale points for user',
    'config'  => [
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'pages',
        'maxitems' => 999999,
        'suggestOptions' => [
            'default' => [
                'searchWholePhrase' => 1
            ],
            'pages' => [
                'searchCondition' => 'doktype = 254'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

[image]

Comment: `group` has the big advantage of having the possibility of selecting/grouping *different* record-types. But that could be the disadvantage on the other hand: it's hard to select/render the items performant. Maybe, changing to a `type=select` would increase the performance - as you are allowing only 'pages'.

Comment: Question is if it's a TYPO3 issue or a browser issue. Did you verify the transferred HTML and JS of the BE site?

Comment: @David nice try, but that's not the issue, I checked source code of the frame and it doesn't contain required items.

Comment: Probably you can raise the limit a bit with select fields but also checking if you can make some relations lazy. I never look up now, but perhaps it's only the fe_groups relation. Additionally you can check if the SQL is performant by debugging it and optimize in phpmyadmin. I know concerning mm-connections it's very terrible but haven't checked for group fields. To change it would be a difficult step but first you can check.  If you changed any fields to save files (instead of references) or long texts / blobs that could be a bottleneck. If image references are saved you can make it lazy too.

Comment: Additionally you can reduce the search fields in TCA, not sure if it could help. If you've the SQL you can perhaps also optimize indexes and some variables in MySQL configuration. In phpmyadmin the variables can be listed and they are marked if values are critical / improvable.

Comment: Beside server RAM and HDD space you finally still could check the swap-partition of the server. Perhaps it should be increased.

Comment: Some TYPO3 caches might be improvable too but I haven't experience with it. As far as I know sometimes Redis is used as cache: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/FrontendsBackends/Index.html#redis-backend

Comment: Just realized, TCA has no lazy option, sorry for confusion. Neverthless showing less fields, at best without relation reduces queries and data amount